# Generate URL from library in Razor Pages

Tags: c#, razor-pages, asp.net-core-3.1

I am trying to generate some URL's to some of my pages from my services which are in a library.

I was trying to use `LinkGenerator` but it didnt have any `GetUriByPage()` as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.routing.linkgenerator?view=aspnetcore-3.1.

Is there any way to generate Urls from the services that points to the Pages?

p.s. I tried to install `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref` but i get:

```
The package Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref {version} has a package type DotnetPlatform that is incompatible with this project.
```